# Cannot find module problem when i tried to mock a component that is used in the component i want to test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component I want to test. The component has 2 different components that are used in it. I want to test only the component, not the components that are used in it. Because they could break the test. My parent component like that:

```
import PageTop from '../page-top'
import TrackingMap from '../tracking-map'
const AppContainer = () => {
return (
<div>
 <PageTop/>
 <TrackingMap/>
</div>
)
}
```

My TrackingMap like that:

```
const TrackingMap = () =>{
return (<div>
//there are some process
</div>)
}
```

My PageTop is similar to TrackingMap component. It doesn't matter what includes them.

My test for parent component like that:

```
import { renderWithProviders } from '../../../utils/renderWithProviders'
import constantsTestid from '../../../../src/constants/testid'
import AppContainer from '../../../../src/components/app-container'
import { screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'


describe('app container', () => {
  const testid = constantsTestid.appContainer

  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('../tracking-map', () => () => '{CONTENT}')
    jest.mock('../page-top', () => () => '{PAGE_TOP}')
  })

  test('should be rendered', async () => {
    renderWithProviders(<AppContainer />)

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByTestId(constantsTestid.loading.loadingContainer)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(screen.queryByTestId(testid.top)).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(screen.queryByTestId(testid.content)).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
  })
})
```

But it throws an error like that:

**Cannot find module '../tracking-map' from '**tests**/src/components/app-container/app-container.test.js'**

What is the problem related to this issue? As i know i should adjust the path of the mock like how they are used in the parent component.